# A Integration of GUI based nosql to netbeans ide

Tags: mongodb, oracle-nosql, nosql

Is there any No SQL Database which has GUI like that of Oracle Database instead of command prompt?

I currently want a database with nodes and lists. And I found out MongoDB does not have a GUI.
Also, I want to integrate it into my NeatBeans IDE.

Comment: Have you seen RockMongo?

Answer (score 1):

[NBMongo](https://github.com/le-yams/netbeans-mongodb) is a NetBeans plugin to interact with MongoDB. 
It's available for NetBeans 7.4 and 8.0 (you can install it directly through the NetBeans update center). See also [the plugin page on NetBeans Plugin Portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52638/nbmongo).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous third party GUIs for MongoDB listed [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Oracle Database offers a desktop client. If that's what you are looking for there might be something out there [1](http://mongohub.todayclose.com)

Now if what you are looking for can also be a web interface, then I'd recommend taking a look at [RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com) which offers an exquisite admin and data explorer, but also [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org).